# Scala: Find value in nested map (parsed from JSON)

Tags: json, scala

I converted a JSON to a very complex nested map. 
I only need one value out of this map. It is the field "system".
In my example the value is "DEV130PHYSTEST".
Can anyone help me to find this value in this map with Scala?

```
Some(Map(type -> SUCCESS, msg -> Container D4SContRules successfully called., result -> Map(execution-results -> Map(results -> List(Map(key -> , value -> 1.0), Map(key -> output, value -> List(Map(demo.d4srules.inputObj -> Map(order -> 1.0)), Map(demo.d4srules.outputObj -> Map(system -> DEV130PHYSTEST)))), Map(key -> input, value -> Map(demo.d4srules.inputObj -> Map(order -> 1.0)))), facts -> List(Map(key -> input, value -> Map(org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle -> Map(external-form -> 0:1:1400441403:1400441403:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:demo.d4srules.inputObj))))))))
```

As an alternative we could also start with the JSON:

```
{
    "type": "SUCCESS",
    "msg": "Container D4SContRules successfully called.",
    "result": {
        "execution-results": {
            "results": [{
                    "key": "",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "output",
                    "value": [{
                            "demo.d4srules.inputObj": {
                                "order": 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "demo.d4srules.outputObj": {
                                "system": "DEV130PHYSTEST"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "input",
                    "value": {
                        "demo.d4srules.inputObj": {
                            "order": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "facts": [{
                "key": "input",
                "value": {
                    "org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {
                        "external-form": "0:1:1640380:1640380:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:demo.d4srules.inputObj"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some json library for scala? Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if I understood it correctly, what you want is some way to find a value for a key that is stored in a `Map` that is potentially deep inside some complicated hierarchical data structure and you don't know or don't want to hardcode the path to it. If this is the case, you may try something like this:

```
def findValueForKeyDeep[Key](container: Any, key: Key): Option[Any] = {
  @tailrec
  def findValueForKeyInTraversable(tr: Traversable[_], key: Key): Option[Any] = {
    if (tr.isEmpty) None
    else {
      val headRes = findValueForKeyDeep(tr.head, key)
      if (headRes.isDefined) headRes else findValueForKeyInTraversable(tr.tail, key)
    }
  }

  container match {
    case m: scala.collection.Map[Key, _] => m.get(key).orElse(findValueForKeyInTraversable(m.values, key))
    case o: Option[_] => o.flatMap(findValueForKeyDeep(_, key))
    case tr: Traversable[_] => findValueForKeyInTraversable(tr, key)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Example:

```
val jsonObj = Some(Map(
  "type" -> "SUCCESS",
  "msg" -> "Container D4SContRules successfully called.",
  "result" ->
    Map(
      "execution-results" ->
        Map(
          "results" -> List(
            Map(
              "key" -> "",
              "value" -> 1.0),
            Map(
              "key" -> "output",
              "value" -> List(
                Map("demo.d4srules.inputObj" -> Map("order" -> 1.0)),
                Map("demo.d4srules.outputObj" -> Map("system" -> "DEV130PHYSTEST")))),
            Map(
              "key" -> "input",
              "value" -> Map("demo.d4srules.inputObj" -> Map("order" -> 1.0)))),
          "facts" -> List(
            Map("key" -> "input",
              "value" -> Map("org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle" -> Map("external-form" -> "0:1:1400441403:1400441403:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:demo.d4srules.inputObj"))))))))

println(findValueForKeyDeep(jsonObj, "system"))
println(findValueForKeyDeep(jsonObj, "external-form"))
println(findValueForKeyDeep(jsonObj, "value"))
println(findValueForKeyDeep(jsonObj, "order"))
println(findValueForKeyDeep(jsonObj, "bad key"))
```

> Some(DEV130PHYSTEST) 
>   Some(0:1:1400441403:1400441403:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:demo.d4srules.inputObj)  
>   Some(1.0)  
>   Some(1.0)  
>   None

Note that if there are several matching keys, this code returns value for some of them (arbitrary). Note also that return type is `Option[Any]` but if you sure about the actual type, you can cast to it using `asInstanceOf` after the call.

**Update** (find all matching values)

If you want to get all the values, you can do it as easily

```
  def findAllValuesForKeyDeep[Key](container: Any, key: Key): List[Any] = {
    @tailrec
    def findAllValuesForKeyDeepImpl(container: Any, key: Key, acc: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
      container match {
        case m: scala.collection.Map[Key, _] => {
          val valueOption = m.get(key)
          if (valueOption.isDefined)
            valueOption.get :: acc
          else
            findAllValuesForKeyDeepImpl(m.values, key, acc)
        }
        case Some(v) => findAllValuesForKeyDeepImpl(v, key, acc)
        case tr: Traversable[_] => findAllValuesForKeyInTraversable(tr, key, acc)
        case _ => acc
      }
    }

    @tailrec
    def findAllValuesForKeyInTraversable(tr: Traversable[_], key: Key, acc: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
      if (tr.isEmpty) acc
      else {
        val headAcc = findAllValuesForKeyDeepImpl(tr.head, key, acc)
        findAllValuesForKeyInTraversable(tr.tail, key, headAcc)
      }
    }

    findAllValuesForKeyDeepImpl(container, key, List.empty[Any])
  }
```

but beware that now you can't simple cast `List[Any]` to something more specific and if you are sure that you know the type of all elements and it is the same, use `map` to convert values such as

```
findAllValuesForKeyDeep(jsonObj, "order").map(v => v.asInstanceOf[Double])
```

Comment: @Michael, if this answer helps, mark it as Accpeted

Comment: Hallo @SergGr....would it be hard to refactor the code in a way that the methode returns ALL values for one key?
Can you give me a hint or a solution ;-)?
Thankx

Comment: @Michael, see my update for `findAllValuesForKeyDeep`

Comment: @SergGr i'm trying to compile your finallAllValuesForKeyDeep but it does throw warning `abstract type Key in type pattern scala.collection.Map[Key,_] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` and doesnt compile after this. I did tried with adding TypeTag as `scala.collection.Map[Key,TypeTag[ <: Any]]` and compile it but fails with error: not found: type _$1 .